# How to vote during promotion phase

Tags: voting

How can bakers cast their vote during the promotion phase? As far as I can see it's not included in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> ./tezos-client submit ballot for "name of your baker"
>   Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd < yay|nay >

Comment: Don't forget "pass"! So, < yay|nay|pass >